# Create funnels that multiple users interact with

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We have a funnel we want to track and there are 2 users that affect the flow of the funnel.

One does a few steps, and after this, the other user interacts with the data, the first user accepts, in the end the second user converts.

In order to better explain how this works.

```
User 1             || User 2     || User 1       || User 2
Create application -> Give offer -> Accept offer -> Grant offer
```

Is there any way to create a funnel that helps use have a better overview of where people drop off along the way?

Or should we better create smaller funnels for each of the user's steps?

Comment: You're asking about how you can see where the "cooperation" with users interrupts?

Comment: Yes, that is part of what we want to find out about users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting one. My quick solution will use Google Analytics' event tracking. Conversion funnels are per user's session, while with events you can record actions taken on your site by different users.

What I would do is that for each process I would create a unique ID that will be shared by the users that are involved in the application. 
Then for each step I will create an Event on Google Analytics that will always include the ID in question, like the following:

```
Category:Application sequence

Action: Step1 OR Step2 OR Step3 OR Step4

Label: {application ID}
```

Then in your reports you can export all the events and see which steps are the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

With Google Analytics, you can only take advantage of Goal flow and Ecommerce tracking.

Goals needs to be different for each step, because GA doesn't count multiple goals.

Here you can see their differences https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en

Even if you're not selling goods or services, just try to use Ecommerce tracking (so you need some imagination) for understanding at a session level where there's a break-up in the cooperation.

Also, use personalized dimensions to distinguish "User 1" from "User 2" in goal flow.

You can also consider Piwik as analytics software, because it can count multiple goal